# Corona, system.scheduleNotification not working properly

Tags: lua, system, coronasdk, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to implement an app with a local notification system. The system should cancel some unnecessary notifications. System.scheduleNotification works fine (it creates notifications and they work fine) but it returns `nil` (It supposed to return an ID). So I'm not able to cancel any notifications by notification id.

Actually the code I use is very simple. Any help would be helpful...

```
local nextRefreshTime = 60 -- Not always 60, its just an example
local options = {
    alert = "Some text here.",
    badge = ( native.getProperty( "applicationIconBadgeNumber" ) or 0 ) + 1,
}

notifications[#notifications+1] = system.scheduleNotification( nextRefreshTime, options )
print(notifications[#notifications]) -- Prints nil !?!
-- Another example (test)
print( system.scheduleNotification( nextRefreshTime, options ) ) -- Also prints nil !?!
```

p.s: I also tried `system.scheduleNotification` with `utcTime` argument.

Answer (score 3):

Are you building the app for `corona simulator`? Then it won't work. Build it for `Xcode simulator` for testing local notifications. A sample project(from `corona Sample Code`) output image is shown below:

[image]

And the code is:

```
local options = {
   alert = "Wake up!",
   badge = 1,
   sound = "alarm.caf",
   custom = { msg = "bar" }
}

notificationID = system.scheduleNotification( time, options )

local displayText = "Notification using Time: " .. tostring( notificationID )
print( displayText ) -- It will print the user data
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Comment: I tried on device and also xcode simulator. I'll try this example. I assume it's on corona site. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post all of your code so I have no idea what your code is doing.  Make sure that in options your alert is a string.  It should look something like this:

```
local options = {
    alert = "Wake up!",
    badge = 2,
}
```

Keep in mind your code is saying your system notication is adding 1 to the notification table.  Right now `system.scheduleNotification` isn't a `string`, it's a table, so when your trying to `print(notifications[#notification])` it would make sense that it prints `nil`.  I think you would have to print out `notification[alert]` but I'm not sure. Check out this link: `http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial`